# time complexity issues for set and vector stl c++

Tags: vector, stl, set, time-complexity

what is the difference in time between accessing element in a set and vector and between for example :

```
int val = 5;
set <int> a;
int x = *lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), val); // i got time limit exceed 
int y = *a.lower_bound(val); // i got accepted time
```

Comment: I see no mention of `vector` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're making two different calls here:

- first, there's the free function `std::lower_bound` that takes two iterators and a value
- second, you're calling the member function `std::set::lower_bound`, which takes a set (implicitly) and a value.

The first routine is a general implementation of `lower_bound` and does a binary search for the answer. Since `std::set::const_iterator` is not random-access, that requires a lot of forward and backwards link tracking (first, advance to the middle, etc).

The second routine has knowledge of the underlying set (implemented as a tree). It starts at the root, and walks down the tree to find the value that it needs. This is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Are you speaking about complexity?

For the `std::vector`, as from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

> Random access - constant O(1)
>
> Insertion or removal of elements at the end - amortized constant O(1)
>
> Insertion or removal of elements - linear in distance to the end of the vector O(n)

For a `std::unordered_set`, as from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set):

> Search, insertion, and removal have average constant-time complexity.

The *difference in time* does not make much sense, for it depends on a lot of factors (as an example, how can it be the same on an i7 and a mobile phone?)

Comment: so it's different time when lower bound searches in set than a vector ?